# What would be the value of, a variable assigned to On Error Resume Next?

Tags: vb6, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I have started reverse engineering and using *visual basic decompiler*, I got this, although it's basic, only thing I don't understand ( is this piece of code ) :

```
  loc_00405255: On Error Resume Next
  loc_00405262: -1 = Time$
  loc_0040526D: var_30 = On Error Resume Next
  loc_00405273: edi = Date$
  loc_0040527E: var_34 = var_30
```

**Is what would `var_30` contain ?**

#### EDIT 2 :

**Cause I from the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/on-error-statement), I don't see  `On Error Resume Next` doesn't return anything .**

Below is the part of the whole section of code :

```
Dim var_140 As Variant
  loc_00405255: On Error Resume Next
  loc_00405262: -1 = Time$
  loc_0040526D: var_30 = On Error Resume Next
  loc_00405273: edi = Date$
  loc_0040527E: var_34 = var_30
  loc_004052B7: var_24 = Text2.Text
  loc_004052BF: var_144 = var_24
  loc_00405301: var_168 = var_24
  loc_00405314: var_C4 = var_168
  loc_00405357: var_28 = Text1.Text
  loc_0040535F: var_14C = var_28
  loc_004053A8: Asc(var_28) = Asc(var_28) + 0001h
  loc_004053C3: var_16C = var_30
  loc_004053D6: var_54 = var_16C
  loc_0040540B: var_2C = var_34
  loc_00405418: var_84 = Right$(var_2C, 2)
  loc_00405428: var_E4 = "Grand-Theft-Auto-Vice-City"
  loc_0040543C: var_F4 = "bbidhan-ThE-Great"
  loc_004054AF: var_150 = (var_168 = Chr(Asc(var_28)) & Right(var_16C, 2) & Right$(var_2C, 2) & "Grand-Theft-Auto-Vice-City" & "bbidhan-ThE-Great")
  loc_0040552B: If var_150 = 0 Then GoTo loc_004057C2
  loc_00405588: var_38 = Global.App
  loc_0040558D: var_144 = var_38
  loc_004055E5: var_24 = Global.Path
  loc_004055EA: var_14C = var_24
```

#### EDIT 1 :

**Q2.** `Right(var_16C, 2) & Right$(var_2C, 2)`

Difference between the above two, with the **$** sign ?

Comment: VB.NET is not the same as VBA, and to me this looks like VB6. Can you confirm which is one correct?

Comment: Sorry, it's actually VB6

Comment: Then it's not related to VB.NET either ;). If I had to guess, `var_30` would contain information about the error that occurred, if there was one. Though as I said this is only guesswork.

Comment: @VisualVincent `Right(var_16C, 2)`

what about this ?

Comment: Seems like it extracts part of the error message (if that is what `var_30` contains). Here's the documentation for the VB.NET `Right()` function (it works the same as in VB6): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxs6hz0a(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @VisualVincent what if there's no error, `Right` function would throw a **ArgumentException** error. But I don't see that in this case ( one thing is that, there isn't any exception handling for that ).

Comment: Hmm, don't know. As I said I only guessed what `var_30` would contain. Though since it has `On Error Resume Next` it shouldn't display any errors at all (not even from the `Right()` function). Perhaps the decompiler didn't decompile it correctly? I've never decompiled a VB6 application before so I don't really know.

Comment: I'd recommend regarding the decompilation listing with a grain of salt - original code info is lost during compilation, so you'll only get so close to the original.  `On Error` doesn't have a return value, so that's something the decompiler got wrong, essentially. After the `On Error Resume Next` any exceptions will be ignored, so if the `Right` function call would otherwise throw an exception, there will be no assigned value and the variable will retain it's previous value.

Comment: `Right` returns a Variant (string) while `Right$` returns a string. For most purposes, the differences between these can be ignored - they're pretty much equivalent (though not exactly).

Comment: In Vb6 `On Error Resume Next` is a statement and does not return a value, as [described in the VB6 docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266173(v=vs.60).aspx). [You linked to the Vb.Net docs.] The decompiler is lying to you.

Comment: It's probably the internal variable that holds what to do when an error occurs.

Comment: `—1 = Time$` looks rather odd also

Answer (score 3):

`On Error` is [a statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266173%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), not an expression. Saying `some_variable = On Error` is a syntax error.

It appears that your decompiler is attempting to use that syntax to communicate something, but whatever it's trying to communicate isn't something expressible in VB6, and certainly not something I intuitively understand from looking at it either. It may be trying to tell you about some internal bookkeeping used to keep track of error information, or it may just be a bug in the decompiler you're using. It's not a meaningful expression.